Glide adds black corners when loading an image to ShapeableImageView which is not attached to window
I need to share an image that is dynamically created with a profile image. The image is never visible to the user in the app.
Steps:

Create the custom view programmatically
Create the bitmap image of the view
Create the URI of the bitmap
Share the URI on social media

My problem is that Glide adds an unintended black corner to the image.

Note: It worked perfectly when I tried to make the view visible to the
user (by adding the custom view to the activity layout) and then continued with the 2. step.

 
Layout of the view view_profile_summary.xml:


...

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/profileSummaryCardView"
    android:layout_width="217dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/profileSummaryDescriptionTextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profileSummaryAppIconImageView"
    app:strokeColor="@color/white"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp"
    tools:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileSummaryImageView"
            android:layout_width="213dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/profileSummaryNicknameTextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlayCardCustomCornersTop30"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_empty_profile_image"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
  
            ...

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

...       

         



Shape appearance overlay:


<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlayCardCustomCornersTop30" parent="">
            <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
            <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">30dp</item>
            <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">30dp</item>
            <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
            <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
</style>



ProfileSummaryView custom view:


class ProfileSummaryView @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context,
attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

   val  binding = ViewProfileSummaryBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, false)
}



Create the view and load image with Glide: (Activity)


runOnUiThread {
    val view = ProfileSummaryView(this)
    val imageLayoutParams = view.binding.profileSummaryImageView.layoutParams
    val imageWidth = imageLayoutParams.width
    val imageHeight = imageLayoutParams.height

    Glide.with(this@MyActivity)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .override(imageWidth, imageHeight)
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .load(url)
                    .into(object : BitmapImageViewTarget(view.binding.profileSummaryImageView) {
                        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                            super.onResourceReady(resource, transition)
                            createUriAndShare(view)
                        }
                    })
}



Creating Bitmap and URI: (Activity) - Probably it is not relevant with this part


private fun createUriAndShare(view: ProfileSummaryView) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        delay(1000L)
        val layoutParams = view.binding.root.layoutParams
        val width = layoutParams.width
        val height = layoutParams.height
        view.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        )
        view.layout(0, 0, width, height)
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        view.draw(canvas)
        bitmap?.let {
            val stickerUri = saveBitmapAndGetUri(it)
            shareImage(stickerUri)
        }
    }
}

private fun saveBitmapAndGetUri(bitmap: Bitmap): Uri? {
    try {
        val cachePath = File(cacheDir, "images")
        cachePath.mkdirs()
        val file = File(cachePath, "image.jpg")
        val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream)
        fileOutputStream.flush()
        fileOutputStream.close()
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "$packageName.provider", file)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}

private fun shareImage(imageUri: Uri?) {
    if (imageUri == null) {
        return
    }
    val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    shareIntent.setType("image/*")
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri)
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share your profile"))
}



